# Java Instance Variable Accessibility

Tags: java, variables, inheritance

What is the difference in the accessibility of the following variables in Java?

```
public class Joe {
    public int a;
    protected int b;
    private int b;
    int c;
}
```

I'm most interested in what the last one is doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `public`: read/writable for anyone
- `protected`: read/writable for
  instances of subclasses **and from within the enclosing package**
- `private`: read/writable for **any** instance of the class
  and inner or outer (enclosing) instance
- `int c`:
  package-private, read/writable for
  all classes inside same package

See the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#104285) for more details

EDIT: Added the comment for protected stating that access is granted from inside same package, you guys are totally right. Also added comment for `private`. I remember now... ;-)

Comment: I believe you are wrong about protected.  In Java protected means package-private.  It's the C# equivalent to internal

Comment: No, he's absolutely _right_ about the protected and r/w for subclasses. dhiller even provided a link to the language spec where it is explained in detail.

Comment: Read the spec more carefully, it denotes that the type of the instance must be a class or subclass.  It makes no note of where the type instance is used from.

Comment: A clearer explanation is available at javacamp http://www.javacamp.org/javavscsharp/access.html

Comment: Actually, the third one isn't quite right either: private instance variables can be accessed by _any_ instance of that class.

Comment: ...which is what is said in the javacamp link : "Access limited to the containing type", not the containing instance.

Comment: Protected variables (and methods) can be accessed from subclasses, but also from *any* other classes in the same package.

Comment: Yes, guys you are right!. I've added a comment to make that clear

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for answering corrections to one previous answer but I don't have enough reputation to modify directly...

- `public` - read/writable for anyone
- `protected` - read/writable for
  instances subclasses and all classes
  inside same package
- `int c` : package-private,
  read/writable for all classes inside
  same package
- `private` - read/writable for any member of that class itself and inner classes (if any)

It is better to order the access modifiers this way, from the broadest access (`public`) to the narrowest (`private`), knowing that when going from narrow to broad, you don't lose any possibilities.

That's particularly important for "protected", where it is often misunderstood that classes in the same package can also access protected members of a class (not only its subclasses).

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid package level access completely (the last access you mention).

I like to keep classes self-contained. If another class needs access to something in my class it should be `public` (and it should by a method, not an attribute). Otherwise I feel you've broken [encapsulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99688/private-vs-public-members-in-practice-how-important-is-encapsulation#100035), as explained in [Abstraction VS Information Hiding VS Encapsulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626/abstraction-vs-information-hiding-vs-encapsulation).

Comment: Sometimes package-private comes in handy for unit testing though. But basically I think you're right.

Comment: @WMR: right, but it could be argued that unit testing could use Reflection to access private data or test protected/private methods... (if the SecurityManager allows it)

Comment: Package-private should be the default for top-level classes and interfaces. The are certain rare situations where it is appropriate (in the absence of friends).

Answer (score 0):

And all of these are compile time protections, they can be readily overridden through reflection at runtime.

Comment: Unless the SecurityManager says otherwise ;)