# Java Class Accessibility

Tags: java, class, accessibility

Slightly related to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267750/java-instance-variable-accessibility): What is the difference between the following:

```
private class Joe
protected class Joe
public class Joe
class Joe
```

Once again, the difference between the last 2 is what I'm most interested in.

Comment: I've only just read your other question. Given the answers to that one, this question is redundant. Yes, they're slightly different questions - but the references given cover class accessibility as well as variables.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A public class is accessible to a class in any package.

A class with default access (`class Joe`) is only visible to other classes in the same package.

The private and protected modifiers can only be applied to inner classes.

A private class is only visible to its enclosing class, and other inner classes in the same enclosing class.

A protected class is visible to other classes in the same package, and to classes that extend the enclosing class.

Answer (score 1):

- private: visible for outer classes only
- protected: visible for outer classes only
- public: visible for all other classes
- class: package-private, so visible for classes within the same package

See [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#104285) for more info.

Comment: What is this?! Downvote without explanation? Guys, this really sucks!

Answer (score 1):

[A class with default access](http://java-expert.blogspot.com/2007/07/class-declarations-and-modifiers.html) has no modifier preceding it in the declaration.

The [default access](http://java-expert.blogspot.com/2007/07/class-declarations-and-modifiers.html) is a package-level access, because a class with default access can be seen only by classes within the same package.

If a class has default access, **a class in another package won’t be able to create a instance of that class, or even declare a variable or return type**. The compiler will complain. For example:

```
package humanity;
class Person {}

package family;
import humanity.Person;
class Child extends Person {}
```

Try to compile this 2 sources. As you can see, they are in different packages, and the compilation will fail.