# Should methods that are required to be executed in a specific order be private?

Tags: c#

I have a Class that retrieves some data and images does some stuff to them and them uploads them to a third party app using web services.
The object needs to perform some specific steps in order.
My question is should I be explicitly exposing each method publicly like so.

```
myObject obj = new myObject();
obj.RetrieveImages();
obj.RetrieveAssociatedData();
obj.LogIntoThirdPartyWebService();
obj.UploadStuffToWebService();
```

or should all of these methods be private and encapsulated in a single public method like so.

```
public class myObject()
{
 private void RetrieveImages(){};
 private void RetrieveAssociatedData(){};
 private void LogIntoThirdPartyWebService(){};
 private void UploadStuffToWebService(){};

 public void DoStuff()
  {
   this.RetrieveImages();
   this.RetrieveAssociatedData();
   this.LogIntoThirdPartyWebService();
   this.UploadStuffToWebService();
  }
}
```

which is called like so.

```
myObject obj = new myObject();
obj.DoStuff();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use public/private/static methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793494/when-should-i-use-public-private-static-methods)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It depends on who knows that the methods should be called that way.

- **Consumer knows:** For example, if the object is a `Stream`, usually the *consumer* of the Stream decides when to `Open`, `Read`, and `Close` the stream. Obviously, these methods need to be public or else the object can't be used properly. (*)
- **Object knows:** If the *object* knows the order of the methods (e.g. it's a `TaxForm` and has to make calculations in a specific order), then those methods should be private and exposed through a single higher-level step (e.g. `ComputeFederalTax` will invoke `CalculateDeductions`, `AdjustGrossIncome`, and `DeductStateIncome`).
- If the number of steps is more than a handful, you will want to consider a `Strategy` instead of having the steps coupled directly into the object. Then you can change things around without mucking too much with the object or its interface.

In your specific case, it does not appear that a consumer of your object cares about anything other than a processing operation taking place. Since it doesn't need to know about the order in which those steps happen, there should be just a single public method called `Process` (or something to that effect).

---

(*) However, usually the object knows at least the *order* in which the methods can be called to prevent an invalid state, even if it doesn't know *when* to actually do the steps. That is, the object should know enough to prevent itself from getting into a nonsensical state; throwing some sort of exception if you try to call `Close` before `Open` is a good example of this.

Answer (score 14):

If method B() truly cannot be called unless A() is called first, then proper design dictates that A should return some object that B requires as a parameter.

Whether this is always practical is another matter, but that's how it *should* be done.

Comment: I intuitively like this answer, but I'm not sure why.  Do you have some reference that would explain a bit more why this is so?

Comment: @Daniel It is the only way to enforce call order through the design of your code. I first heard it in a session with Bob Martin.

Comment: @Rex: I suspect the reason that you don't see this a lot is because it's rarely practical to enforce call order this way. Also, this is effectively what you're doing if you just have a sequence of methods anyway: the "object that B requires" is simply `this`, and if `this` isn't in the right state, you throw an exception.

Comment: @John indeed it is often impractical. Though I'm not sure your example is exactly the same, since you are talking about a runtime error and I'm talking about a compile-time error.

Comment: @Rex M: Right, where it would be caught is different. However, that's a language-specific issue rather than a general design question (in Ruby, for example, there would be no difference).

Comment: I suspect this is what his code should be doing.  It looks like rather than return object to pass to the next method, he is using class state to hold the data that should be being transferred, otherwise what is the method RetrieveImages doing?

Answer (score 4):

Yes private, otherwise you are leaving the door open for users to do things wrong, which will only be a cause for pain for everyone.

Do you ever need to call any of these methods on its own?  ie does any of them do anything which is useful and might be needed stand alone?  if so then you might want to keep those public, but even if you keep them all public, you should have the method which calls them in the correct order (preferably with a useful name) to make things easier for your users.

Comment: could downvoters please explain the reasons?

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on whether the operation is essentially atomic. In this case it looks like a single operation to us outsiders, but is it really? If `LogIntoThirdPartyWebService` fails, does the UI need to present a dialog box to ask the user if they want to retry? In the case where you have a single operation, retrying the `LogIntoThirdPartyWebService` operation also requires redoing potentially expensive operations like `RetrieveImages`, while making them separate enables more granular logic.

What I would do in this case is something like this:

```
Images images = RetrieveImages();
ImagesAndData data = RetrieveAssociatedData(images);
WebService webservice = LogIntoThirdPartyWebService();
UploadStuffToWebService(data, webservice);
```

or maybe more ideally something like this:

```
UploadStuffToWebService(RetrieveImages().RetrieveAssociatedData(),
                        LogIntoThirdPartyWebService());
```

Now you have granularity while enforcing the proper order of operations.

Comment: +1 it seems like his class is probably storing a lot of data internally which various methods in the process will be reliant on.

Comment: Why the downvote? I suggested the same thing as Rex M, and nobody downvoted his answer.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like from the consumer of your object's point of view, the object does one thing: it moves images from one place to another.  As the consumer of the object, all of the individual steps you need to take to accomplish that are irrelevant to me; after all that's why I have you to do it for me.

So you should have a single `DoStuff()` method that takes all the necessary params, and make all the implementation details private.

Answer (score 2):

Private -- and take the parameters in the constructor and execute the order there.

Do not assume the caller will, or knows how to, call them in order.

So, rather than the example you have listed, I would do it this way:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject(); // make a constructor to take any parameters that are required to "setup" the object per your requirements.
myObject.UploadToWebService();
```

Comment: Merely because something needs to be executed in a certain order doesn't mean it needs to be private. For instance, it doesn't make sense to call `Close` on a `Stream` before you `Open` it, but that doesn't mean we should make those methods private.

Comment: It wasn't a blanket statement regarding everything in general, but based on his description.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on whether you estimate that anyone would want to invoke only one of these methods and whether they make sense individually or can be implemented independently. If not, then it is better to avoid exposing anything but the high level op.

Answer (score 1):

**Expose as little as possible, as much as necessary.** If a call to `FuncA()` is *always* followed by a call to `FuncB()`, make one `public` and have it call the other, or else have `public FuncC()` call them in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should definitely be private, especially as all the methods seem to be parameterless and you're just concerned with the order.

The only time I would consider calling each method explicitly is if they each took several, non-overlapping parameters, and you wouldn't want to pass such a long string of parameters to one method and would want to modularize. And then you should make sure to document it *clearly*. But remember that comments are not executable... You'll still have to trust your user a bit more than you really should.

One of the biggest factors of information hiding and OOP... only give the user what is absolutely necessary. Allow as little room for mess-up as possible.

Comment: another scenario would maybe be if each step takes a disturbingly long time, then maybe splitting it up and doing things in between could be a good thing (if multi-threading isn't doable).

Answer (score 0):

The question of public or private depends entirely on the contract you wish to expose for your object. Do you want users of your object to call the methods individually, or do you want them to call a single "DoStuff" method and be done with it?

It *all* depends on the intended usage of the class.

In the example you've given, I'd say DoStuff should be public and the rest private.

Answer (score 0):

Which do you think would be easier for the consumers of your class?

*Absolutely* write one public method that performs the correct steps in the correct order. Otherwise, the caller is not going to do it right; they're going to forget a step or skip something.

Answer (score 0):

One reason they would be public is if you intend the user to be able to insert logic between steps. In this case, you should impose that the functions are called in the correct order internally by keeping a really tiny state machine.  If the state machine transitions in the wrong order, you have options besides just doing something wrong, such as throwing an exception.

However, an alternative design that allows them all to be remain private if the case of needing to act beween steps does exist.  Instead of making the methods public, provide a public callback interface that lets the users attach handlers that you call at each step of the process.  In your now private doItAll() method, you can do something as granular as:

if(preRetrieveHandlerExists){
  preRetrieveHandler()
}
obj.RetrieveImages();

if(postRetrieveHandlerExists){
  postRetrieveHandler()
}
//so on and so forth

Answer (score 0):

Neither.  I think you have at least 3 objects otherwise you are breaking the Single-Responsibility Principal.  You need an object that "Gets and holds images", one that "manipulates images", and one that "manages external vendor communication".

Answer (score 0):

My software engineering rule of thumb is to always give the user/consumer/caller as little chance to screw things up as possible. Therefore, keep the methods private to ensure working order.

Answer (score 0):

Fowler uses the term "Feature Envy" to describe a situation where one object calls a handful of methods (especially repeatedly) on another.

I don't know where he got it from.  You don't see it much in the literature, and a lot of people over the years have had no idea what I was talking about (I dunno why, I thought the name was perfectly obvious once I heard it.  Which is why I repeat it)