# public vs public static Methods

Tags: c#, static

Having read the access modifiers in C# progamming tutorial, I come to conclusion that defining a method `public` is enough for it to be "seen" from another `Form` of the same namespace.

However, in practise whenever I tried to implement this, I also had to define the method as `static` in order for it to be referenced from other `Forms` of the same namespace.

Am I loosing something?
I am doing somethning wrong?

Comment: Did you create an instance of the class that the method resides in? Was the class marked as static too? Post some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use public/private/static methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793494/when-should-i-use-public-private-static-methods)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a `public static` method, you don't need a reference to an object. The method is static and can be accessed on `class` level.

If you can't access a public method, then you need a reference to the object, then you can.

```
public class AClass
{
    public void DoSomething() {}
    public static void DoSomethingElse() {}
}
```

You can use them as follows:

```
AClass.DoSomethingElse(); // no object reference required
AClass.DoSomething(); // will give compiler error, since you have no object reference.
var anObject = new AClass();
anObject.DoSomething(); // will work fine.
anObject.DoSomethingElse(); // compile error (thx hvd).
```

Comment: "anObject.DoSomethingElse(); // will also work fine" -- Are you sure? Mono's compiler gives a hard error "error CS0176: Static member cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead", and I seem to recall seeing an error for that with Microsoft's compiler as well.

Comment: In fact, that error code CS0176 [is Microsoft's code for that exact error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhcxt2bd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`public static` method do not need object instance, they can be used without creating any instance of the class

`ClassName.MyStaticPublicMethodName()`

where as `public` (non-static) method require an Instance of the Class, public (non-static) method in general helps you to work with the data member (field) of the object.

To use a non-static public method you need to create instance of the class

```
ClassName obj = new ClassName();
obj.MyPublicMethod();
```