# Is adding attributes dynamically frowned upon in Python?

Tags: python, oop, encapsulation, dynamic-languages, design-principles

In Python, you can assign an arbitrary attribute **from outside the defining class**:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)

p = Profile()
p.age = 42
```

The underlying mechanism here is `__dict__` attribute that maintains a dictionary of all attributes.

We were all told [not to expose our inner workings to the client code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99688/private-vs-public-members-in-practice-how-important-is-encapsulation), but attaching *new* data doesn't have to do with encapsulation at all, right? Is this idiom common for Python code?

---

### Just What I Mean…

Each `Tweet` has standard fields, like `id`, `text`, `owner`.
When returning tweet list for a user, you want to display if a tweet is “favorited” by this user.

Obviously, to obtain `is_favorite` you need to query many-to-many relationship for this `user`.
Would it be OK to **pre-fill `Tweet` objects with `is_favorite` corresponding to current user**?

Sure I could expose a method `is_favorite_for(user)` but I'm hitting [Django template language](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=django%20template%20language&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/&ei=9dqqTsO8H-WJ4gT0yvz9Dg&usg=AFQjCNFjUjAirZFu4vUQCUTRlyOvpDCOGg&sig2=qbQhJjNibySNGXMCnd_s6Q) limitations that doesn't allow to call methods with arguments from inside the template. Also, I believe **a template should not be calling methods at all**.

---

I know this will *work* fine, but I wonder if doing something like that in an open source project would get other developers to look on me with contempt.

> Sidenote:
>
> I come from C#/.NET background where dynamic types were introduced very recently and aren't adapted widely except for some niche areas (interoperability, IoC frameworks, REST client frameworks, etc).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My view is that it is a bad practice.

The object doesn't know that you're messing with its attributes. Consider, for example, what would happen if `Profile` were later expanded to have an attribute called `age`, unrelated to `p.age` in your code.

If you want to add attributes, why not subclass `Profile`, or have an external mapping of `Profiles` to an object with your custom attributes?

Comment: though you do get the same pitfall with subclassing

Comment: @Owen: True. IMO the key difference is that with subclassing, the problem is likely to be easier to locate since it's between the base class and the subclass. Adding attributes externally means that the problem code can be *anywhere in the codebase*.

Comment: I expanded a bit on the reasons, I think a `Tweet` and `is_favorite` is a better example than `Person` and `age` here. Subclassing wouldn't make much sense in this case, right?

Comment: @DanAbramov: I am not qualified to comment on Django's limitations, but in plain Python I'd probably put the user's favourites into a `set` rather than making `is_favourite` an attribute of `Tweet`.

Comment: This makes sense. If getting `favorites` is too verbose (in my real app, there are two layers of many-to-many relationships), I could just fetch them into a list in the code and pass them to the template, instead of making `is_favorite` an attribute.

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is: It depends.  First, if you really want to prevent it you can by defining `__slots__` in the class.  And it is not generally a good practice to add attributes not actually defined in the class, as it can be confusing to someone reading
the code and is rarely useful.

But at certain times, it is useful to be able to do this and Python documentation discusses this as a way to get something similar to a C struct or Pascal Record (see  [http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#odds-and-ends) under section 9.7 Odds and Ends.)

Answer (score 3):

If the attribute is only there sometimes, you risk getting an `AttributeError` out of nowhere for one object while the code worked fine for another object of the same class (yes, exact types aren't that important when duck-typing, but objects of the same class are frequently assumed to be of the same "duck type"). Even if it doesn't happen, you can't be sure just by looking at part of the code, and it's much harder to check in any case. So, doing this only makes your code less reliable.

Then there's the option of providing a default attribute as class attribute or property, only assigning an object attribute when it differs from the default. But for stuff that is expected to vary per object, the clarity of having every attribute ever listed in `__init__` usually outweights any potential advantages of delaying instance attribute access.

That is not to say it's not acceptable, but you'd have to make a compelling argument for it to be considered a good idea.