# Information hiding is abstraction or encapsulation?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, encapsulation, abstraction, design-principles

The title says it all, I am bit confused as I was asked a question that Information handling in term of OOP is abstraction or encapsulation?
I opted for abstraction but still I am confused because in encapsulation we also hide the fields and in abstraction we hide the details.
Any help in this regard

Answer (score 1):

It may help if you think of encapsulation as one of the tools used to create abstraction.  See the wikipedia entry for encapsulation here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 1):

`Abstraction` generally hides information, while `Encapsulation` separates the changeable data from the unchanged one. In this way, `Encapsulation` helps to achieve the [`Open Closed Principle`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1927000/1673715e) that I think it clears the confusion

> Encapsulation has two faces; data
>   abstraction and information hiding.
>   Data abstraction is a type seen from
>   the outside. Information hiding is a
>   type seen from the inside.
>
> - Abstraction focuses on the outside view of an object (i.e. the interface)
> - Encapsulation (information hiding ) prevents clients from seeing its
>     inside view, where the behavior of the
>     abstraction is implemented

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation = Hiding the Complexities / information

Abstraction = A (somewhat) defined way to handle complexities, using encapsulation

Comment: Abstraction is handling complexities? it doesn't hide your low level details?

Comment: You are right I edited my answer, I was actually talking about the larger scope of functionality, but its better this way