# Explain encapsulation in OOP

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation

I am new to OOP and I have some doubts regarding encapsulation.

1. What is mean by difference between "partial" and "weak" encapsulation? An example in java will help me.
2. Does encapsulation means only place data in capsule like a class, or does an access modifier have to be there?

I read that encapsulation means to hide and club together data.

In this example:

```
class A{ 
  public int a;
  public void foo(){}
}
```

Is above code is example of encapsulation? If yes, then there is nothing hidden from outer world as `a` and `foo` are public. Must `a` and `foo` be `private` for this example to be considered encapsulation?

Comment: Down vote is appreciated but please help me or comment before down vote.

Comment: The above code is NOT an example of encapsulation as 'a' is visible outside.. Its not hidden... make it private, have public getters and setters and there you go.. It's encapsulated.

Comment: Ok. mean Bean class is the the definition of encapsulation.Because bean class is defined something like that.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960918/how-encapsulation-is-different-from-abstraction-as-a-object-oriented-concept-in

Comment: In real world, You are using your brain. But, Still don't know how brain functions.... that is the encapsulation.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960918/how-encapsulation-is-different-from-abstraction-as-a-object-oriented-concept-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good explanation https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2010-December/012334.html

Basically if you were implementing a java library or API you would aim for strong encapsulation, so that users couldn't access things they aren't supposed to.

Strong encapsulation means that no one can access secret internal variables because you have a proper inheritance heirachy and all that stuff is hidden.

Your example is very weak encapsulation because the variable `a` is public. If your class was an API and `a` was actually `credit_card_details` you would be in big trouble.

For starters you would set those variables as private and use getters and setters to access them.

Overall though, you need something abstracted in order to encapsulate it. The only other thing I have heard encapsulation refer to from an OOP perspective is simply bundling real world objects into classes

Answer (score 0):

Object orientation is about messages. If you can only ask for setting or getting a value inside an object, then the values are encapsulated. The only way to access them is via the predefined protocol, which is the setter or the getter or whatever other methods.
If you have a public field, it looks like there's no encapsulation, but you still don't own the variable, think of it as a default set or get.