# why we use encapsulation and abstraction if they are doing same, if both are hiding data?

Tags: c#, oop

Hi I need for Best example with proper answer on these encapsulation and abstration. I have little bit confusion about both.
If both is hiding the data then why there is need to use encapsulation?
Why we use both if they are hiding the data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How abstraction and encapsulation differ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938667/how-abstraction-and-encapsulation-differ)

Comment: also another good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960918/how-encapsulation-is-different-from-abstraction-as-a-object-oriented-concept-in/8960961#8960961

Comment: I am asking about both are doing hiding the data. Why we use both?

Comment: If you read these answers I'm linking you, you would understand that they hide **different** things. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626/abstraction-vs-information-hiding-vs-encapsulation

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation means Hide the complexity of object (ex. Car has engine , carburetor etc , but not need to know to drive a car) .

Abstraction means expose the essential feature of object (ex. Car has wheel, steering , gaire, accelerator, these are essentials to know for driving a car).