# Difference between Encapsulation and Abstraction

Tags: java, oop, language-agnostic, encapsulation, abstraction

I had an interview today. I had a question from **OOP**, about the difference between **Encapsulation** & **Abstraction**?

I replied to my knowledge that **Encapsulation** is basically binding data members & member functions into a single unit called **Class**. Whereas **Abstraction** is basically to hide implementation complexity & provide ease of access to the users. I thought she would be okay with my answer. But she queried if the purpose of both is to hide information then what the actual difference between these two is? I could not give any answer to her.

Before asking this question, I read other threads on StackOverFlow about the difference between these two **OOP**s concepts. But I am not finding myself in a position to convince the interviewer.

Can anyone please justify it with the simplest example?

Comment: I don't know why people compare Abstraction and Encapsulation. Why can't we accept them as two different OOP concepts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between abstraction and encapsulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742341/difference-between-abstraction-and-encapsulation)

Comment: @WpfBee Abstraction has nothing to do with hiding, Just checkout my answer

Answer (score 135, accepted):

**Encapsulation** hides variables or some implementation that may be changed so often **in a class** to prevent outsiders access it directly. They must access it via getter and setter methods.

**Abstraction** is used to hide something too, but in a **higher degree (class, interface)**. Clients who use an abstract class (or interface) do not care about what it was, they just need to know what it can do.

Comment: Perfect. It seems to me that your answer is just targeting my interviewer question. I am trying to re-iterate your reply with a practical example. Please let me know, if it justifies your reply.  Let us take an example of television. Encapsulation is the internal circuits, LEDS, etc that combine to make it a TV. Abstraction is the   on-off, sound, channel setting and other buttons provided to operate  it.

Comment: Guys abstraction has nothing to do with hiding implementation ... abstraction is a method to polymorphicly interact with a class

Comment: @Mortalus - I don't agree your 1st statement "abstraction has nothing to do with hiding implementation". I think, when we start learning Abstraction concept the first thing that we are being taught is that we hide complexity of the implementation and provide some interface to user to use it. Because user may not be interested  in implementation complexity. You can take a practical example of TV or AC. The another thing is that if it does not hide implementation then why we provide a method in abstract class that do not have body. We are clearly hiding the implementation here.

Comment: @Mortalus - Also, you mentioned a wiki link. It's first statement -  "In computer science, abstraction is the process by which data and programs are defined with a representation similar in form to its meaning (semantics), while hiding away the implementation details. Abstraction tries to reduce and factor out details so that the programmer can focus on a few concepts at a time." itself suggests that Abstraction is intended to hide the implementation.  I am agree with your 2nd statement but not with 1st.

Comment: Sorry if it sound stupid. I don’t understand the line “abstraction can be implemented using interface of abstract class”. Can’t it be implemented using concrete class as it will also hide implementation details and show essentials using proper access modifiers?

Comment: I think Encapsulation is just more about building a single unit, its not much about you hide it or not. Where as Abstraction is more about hiding things, please correct if i am wrong.

Comment: Exactly Who do you mean by "outsiders" in encapsulation.

Comment: With no assumption of programming language, I think Encapsulation is about packing all data in one unit to reduce the complexity of communication, whereas Abstraction is about exposing methods to interact with objects.

Answer (score 39):

This image sums pretty well the difference between both:

[image]

Source [here](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-abstraction-and-encapsulation/)

Answer (score 28):

**Encapsulation:** Wrapping code and data together into a single unit. `Class` is an example of encapsulation, because it wraps the method and property.

**Abstraction:** Hiding internal details and showing functionality only. Abstraction focus on what the object does instead of how it does. It provides generalized view of classes.

```
int number = 5;
string aStringNumber = number.ToString();
```

Here, ToString() is abstraction. And how this mechanism `number` variable converted to string and initialize into `aStringNumber` is encapsulation.

*Let us take a real world example of calculator. Encapsulation is the internal circuits, battery, etc., that combine to make it a calculator. Abstraction is the different buttons like on-off, clear and other buttons provided to operate it.*

Answer (score 15):

Abstraction - is the process (and result of this process) of identifying the common essential characteristics for a set of objects.
One might say that Abstraction is the process of generalization: all objects under consideration are included in a superset of objects, all of which possess given properties (but are different in other respects).

Encapsulation - is the process of enclosing data and functions manipulating this data into a single unit, so that to hide the internal implementation from the outside world.

This is a general answer not related to a specific programming language (as was the question). So the answer is: abstraction and encapsulation have nothing in common. But their implementations might relate to each other (say, in Java: Encapsulation - details are hidden in a class, Abstraction - details are not present at all in a class or interface).

Answer (score 11):

Yes !!!!
If I say **Encapsulation is a kind of an advanced specific scope abstraction**,

How many of you read/upvote my answer. Let's dig into why I am saying this.

I need to clear two things before my claim.

One is data hiding and,  another one is the abstraction

#### Data hiding

Most of the time, we will not give direct access to our internal data. Our internal data should not go out directly that is an outside person can't access our internal data directly. It's all about security since we need to protect the internal states of a particular object.

#### Abstraction

For simplicity, hide the internal implementations is called abstraction. In abstraction, we only focus on the necessary things. Basically, We talk about "What to do" and not "How to do" in abstraction.
Security also can be achieved by abstraction since we are not going to highlight "how we are implementing". Maintainability will be increased since we can alter the implementation but it will not affect our end user.

I said, "Encapsulation is a kind of an advanced specific scope abstraction".  Why? because we can see encapsulation as data hiding + abstraction

> encapsulation  =  data hiding  +  abstraction

In encapsulation, we need to hide the data so the outside person can not see the data and we need to provide methods that can be used to access the data. These methods may have validations or other features inside those things also hidden to an outside person. So here, we are hiding the implementation of access methods and it is called abstraction.

This is why I said like above encapsulation is a kind of abstraction.

So Where is the **difference**?

The difference is the abstraction is a general one if we are hiding something from the user for simplicity, maintainability and security and,

encapsulation is a specific one for which is related to internal states security where we are hiding the internal state (data hiding) and we are providing methods to access the data and those methods implementation also hidden from the outside person(abstraction).

**Why we need abstraction**
When you do designs, you will not talk about implementations. You say If you give these parameters to this method it will give these output.
We hide the internal implementation of the method and talk about what it will do so this is an abstraction.

Example

```
public int add(int a, int b);
```

This method definition tells us that if you give two variables it will do addition and return the result.

here we will not look at the implementation and we ay only what this method does and not how it does.
Method implementations can be differs based on developers.
1.

```
public int add(int a, int b){
   return a + b; 
}
```

2. 

```
public int add(int a, int b){

   return b + a; 
}
```

Two methods are doing the same thing what their implementation differs.

Basically,

### Abstraction is needed to model the system. Encapsulation is needed to enhance system security.

Comment: This might be a good explanation but still it doesn't answer the question, I guess. The actual question is, if both are about hiding data (and one is a specialization of the other as you have said), then why they are **separate** concepts in OOPS? If a person is a millionaire and a billionaire then we usually omit the millionaire part. get it? (text books lists abstraction, encapsulation, inheritance and polymorphism as the 4 concepts of OOPs)

Comment: @MidhunrajRPillai, I updated the answer with where the abstraction is used

Comment: @RCvaram I liked the last line of your answer

Answer (score 8):

**Abstraction:**
Is usually done to provide polymorphic access to a set of classes.
An abstract class cannot be instantiated thus another class will have to derive from it to create a more concrete representation.

A common usage example of an abstract class can be an implementation of a template method design pattern where an abstract injection point is introduces so that the concrete class can implement it in its own "concrete" way.

see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)

**Encapsulation:**
It is the process of hiding the implementation complexity of a specific class from the client that is going to use it, keep in mind that the "client" may be a program or event the person who wrote the class.

see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: abstraction is related to abstract class??

Comment: @vishnuviswanath, yes, we can implement abstraction using abstract class and interfaces.

Answer (score 8):

There is a great article that touches on differences between Abstraction, Encapsulation and Information hiding in depth: http://www.tonymarston.co.uk/php-mysql/abstraction.txt

Here is the conclusion from the article:

> Abstraction, information hiding, and encapsulation are very different,
>   but highly-related, concepts. One could argue that abstraction is a
>   technique that helps us identify which specific information should be
>   visible, and which information should be hidden. Encapsulation is then
>   the technique for packaging the information in such a way as to hide
>   what should be hidden, and make visible what is intended to be
>   visible.

Answer (score 5):

A very practical example is.

let's just say I want to encrypt my password.

- I don't want to know the details, I just call
  encryptionImpl.encrypt(password) and it returns an encrypted
  password.

  `public interface Encryption{ public String encrypt(String password); }`

  This is called **abstraction**. It just shows what should be done.
- Now let us assume We have Two types of Encryption Md5 and RSA which
  implement Encryption from a third-party encryption jar.

  Then those Encryption classes have their own way of implementing
  encryption which protects their implementation from outsiders

  This is called **Encapsulation**. Hides how it should be done.

Remember:***what should be done vs how it should be done.***

***Hiding complications vs Protecting implementations***

Comment: Nice explanation with example.

Answer (score 4):

Encapsulation:

Hiding something, sort of like medicine capsule. We don't know what is in the capsule, we just take it. Same as in programming - we just hide some special code of method or property and it only gives output, same as capsule. In short, encapsulation hides data.

Abstraction:

Abstraction means hiding logic or implementation. For example, we take tablets and see their color and but don't know what is the purpose of this and how it works with the body.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is true that Abstraction and Encapsulation are about hiding.

- Using only relevant details and hiding unnecessary data at **Design Level** is called **Abstraction**. (Like selecting only relevant properties for a class 'Car' to make it more abstract or general.)
- **Encapsulation** is the hiding of data at **Implementation Level**. Like how to actually hide data from direct/external access. This is done by binding data and methods to a single entity/unit to prevent external access. Thus, encapsulation is also known as data hiding at implementation level.

Comment: Can you explain how this answer differs from the 12 other existing answers?

Answer (score 2):

difference in both is just the **View Point**
Encapsulation word is used for hiding data if our aim is to prevent client seeing inside view of our logic

Abstraction word is used for hiding data if our aim is to show our client a out side view

Outside view means that let suppose

```
BubbleSort(){
//code 
swap(x,y);
}
```

here we use swap in bubble sort for just showing our client what logic we are applying, If we replace swap(x,y) with whole code here, In a single instance he/she can't understand our logic

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain it in with the same example discussed above. Kindly consider the same TV.

**Encapsulation**: The adjustments we can make with the remote is a good example - Volume UP/DOWN, Color & Contrast - All we can do is adjust it to the min and max value provided and cannot do anything beyond what is provided in the remote - Imagine the getter and setter here(The setter function will check whether the value provided is valid if Yes, it process the operation if not won't allow us to make changes - like we cannot decrease the volume beyond zero even we press the volume down button a hundred times).

**Abstraction**: We can take the same example here but with a higher Degree/Context. The volume down button will decrease the volume - and this is the info we provide to the user and the user is not aware of neither the infrared transmitter inside the remote nor the receiver in the TV and the subsequent process of parsing the signal and the microprocessor architecture inside the TV. Simply put it is not needed in the context - Just provide what is necessary. One can easily relate the Text book definition here ie., Hiding the inner implementation and only providing what it will do rather than how it do that!

Hope it clarifies a bit!

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, `Abstraction` happens at class level by hiding implementation and implementing an interface to be able to interact with the instance of the class. Whereas, `Encapsulation` is used to hide information; for instance, making the member variables private to ban the direct access and providing getters and setters for them for indicrect access.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulation is wrapping up of data and methods in a single unit and making the data accessible only through methods(getter/setter) to ensure safety of data.

Abstraction is hiding internal implementation details of how work is done.

Take and example of following stack class:

```
Class Stack
{
private top;
void push();
int pop();
}
```

Now encapsulation helps to safeguard internal data as top cannot be accessed directly outside.

And abstraction helps to do push or pop on stack without worrying about what are steps to push or pop

Answer (score 1):

**Abstraction**
As the name suggests abstract means *summary* or *brief* about somtehing. In case of OOP Abstract Classes are the ones which do not contain every information about that object in real world, for eg. you want to book a hotel room, if your object is that *room* you mainly care about:

- its prices, size, beds etc.

but you do not care about

- the wiring they have used in the hotel room for electricity.
- which cement they have used to build it up

So, you get **abstracted** information about the *room* which you care about.

On the other hand, **Encapsulation** is basically capsulating the related information together, for eg. you booked the hotel room, you go there and switch on a bulb by pressing the *switch*. Now the *switch* object has all internal wirings which are required to switch that bulb ON, but you really do not care about those wirings. You care only about bulb is switched ON or not.

Now one can argue that **abstraction** also applies here:

one can say the internal wiring of the *switch* is also abstracted to you, so this must be case of **abstraction** but here are some subtle differences:

**Abstraction** is more of a contextual thing, it does not have the non abstracted information, like the wiring info which you do not care about, is not present in the context of website for booking hotel *room* (like your class *room* do not have information about the wiring grid of it, since this *room* is delegated for online booking only) , whereas **encapsulation** is more granular, it means hiding and capsulating the granular things which you do not need to care about, for switching the bulb ON the *switch* hides the wiring inside the switch board (like private attributes/methods of classes).
Now the *switch* class has the information but it is hidden to you. On the other hand *room* class does not have the information about wiring design of a hotel room since it is not even in the context of online booking of the *room*

Thus, the **abstraction** is more related to classes and **encapsulation** is more related to internal of the class objects, attributes and methods.

Answer (score 1):

**Abstraction**

- is the process of hiding the how, and only showing the what
- the purpose is to simplify information and hide unnecessary details from the user

**Encapsulation**

- is the process of wrapping data and functionality into a single unit
- the purpose is to protect data, by preventing direct access and only providing a safer and indirect way

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, **Encapsulation** is data hiding(information hiding) while **Abstraction** is detail hiding(implementation hiding)

Answer (score 0):

Abstraction

In Java, abstraction means hiding the information to the real world. It establishes the contract between the party to tell about “what should we do to make use of the service”.

Example, In API development, only abstracted information of the service has been revealed to the world rather the actual implementation. Interface in java can help achieve this concept very well.

Interface provides contract between the parties, example, producer and consumer. Producer produces the goods without letting know the consumer how the product is being made. But, through interface, Producer let all consumer know what product can buy. With the help of abstraction, producer can markets the product to their consumers.

Encapsulation:

Encapsulation is one level down of abstraction. Same product company try shielding information from each other production group. Example, if a company produce wine and chocolate, encapsulation helps shielding information how each product Is being made from each other.

1. If I have individual package one for wine and another one for chocolate, and if all the classes are declared in the package as default access modifier, we are giving package level encapsulation for all classes.
2. Within a package, if we declare each class filed (member field) as
   private and having a public method to access those fields, this way
   giving class level encapsulation to those fields

Answer (score 0):

If I am the one who faced the interview, I would say that as the end-user perspective abstraction and encapsulation are fairly same. It is nothing but information hiding. As a Software Developer perspective, Abstraction solves the problems at the design level and Encapsulation solves the problem in implementation level

Comment: Can you elaborate the answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Encapsulation** is the composition of meaning.

**Abstraction** is the simplification of meaning.

Answer (score -1):

Just a few more points to make thing clear,

One must not confuse data abstraction and the abstract class. They are different.

Generally we say abstract class or method is to basically hide something. But no..  That is wrong. What is the word abstract means ? Google search says the English word abstraction means

"Existing in thought or as an idea but not having a physical or concrete existence."

And thats right in case of abstract class too. It is not hiding the content of the method but the method's content is already empty (not having a physical or concrete existence) but it determines how a method should be (existing in thought or as an idea) or  a method should be in the calss.

So when do you actually use abstract methods ?

- When a method from base class will differ in each child class that extends it.
- And so you want to make sure the child class have this function implemented.
- This also ensures that method, to have compulsory signature like, it must have n number of parameters.

So about abstract class!
- An Abstract class cannot be instantiated only extended! But why ?

- A class with abstract method must be prevented from creating its own instance because the abstract methods in it, are not having any meaningful implementation.
- You can even make a class abstract, if for some reason you find that it is meaning less to have a instance of your that class.

An Abstract class help us avoid creating new instance of it!

An abstract method in a class forces the child class to implement that function for sure with the provided signature!

Comment: Question was about abstraction vs encapsulation, not about abstract class!

Answer (score -4):

Abstraction: what are the minimum functions and variables that should be exposed to the outside of our class.

Encapsulation: how to achieve this requirement, meaning how to implement it.

Comment: Encapsulation is not a means to achieve abstraction. They are 2 slightly different concepts but have a subtle link.

Comment: i think both are not different concepts, bez u can achieve encapsulation with abstract class .