# Use of non static method in Java

Tags: java, methods, static

I want to know, what is the use of the non-static method. My understanding is that static methods can be called directly as well as by the object of the class while nonstatic methods can only be called by an object of the class.

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void print()
    {
        System.out.println("print");
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Ideone id = new Ideone();
        id.print();
        print();
    }
}
```

The above method can be called directly as well as by an object of class. So, when should I have a non static method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993077/difference-between-static-methods-and-instance-methods

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612420/what-is-encapsulation-exactly/28614407

Comment: The question gives the difference between static and instance methods. I want to know when should I use static or non-static methods and if there are any advantages of using non-static methods.

Answer (score 1):

In real-world applications objects interacts with other objects and generally have one starting point say `main` method in some java application.

You CAN NOT invoke other objects nonstatic methods without creating them.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question "when should I have a non static method?"