# Procedural and Data abstraction in ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, abstraction

I'm new to Ruby. I'm learning abstraction principle in ruby.As I understood Procedural abstraction is hiding the implementation details from the user or simply concentrating on the essentials and ignoring the details.

My concern is how to implement it

1) Is it a simple function calling just like this

```
# function to sort array
# @params array[Array] to be sort

def my_sort(array)
  return array if array.size <= 1

  swapped = false
  while !swapped
    swapped = false
    0.upto(array.size-2) do |i|
      if array[i] > array[i+1]
        array[i], array[i+1] = array[i+1], array[i]
        swapped = true
      end
    end
  end

  array
end
```

and calling like this

```
sorted_array = my_sort([12,34,123,43,90,1])
```

2) How does Data Abstraction differs from Encapsulation

As I understood Data Abstraction is just hiding some member data from other classes.

Answer (score 5):

**Data abstraction** is fundamental to most object oriented language - wherein the classes are designed to encapsulate data and provide methods to control how that data is modified (if at all), or helper methods to derive meaning of that data.

Ruby's Array class is an example of Data Abstraction.  It provides a mechanism to manage an array of Objects, and provides operations that can be performed on that array, without you having to care how internally it is organized.

```
arr = [1,3,4,5,2,10]
p arr.class # Prints Array
p arr.sort # Prints [1,2,3,4,5,10]
```

**Procedural abstraction** is about hiding implementation details of procedure from the user.  In the above example, you don't really need to know what sorting algorithm `sort` method uses internally, you just use it assuming that nice folks in Ruby Core team picked a best one for you.

At the same time, Ruby may not know how to compare two items present in the `Array` always.  For example, below code would not run as Ruby does not know how to compare strings and numbers.

```
[1,3,4,5,"a","c","b", 2,10].sort 
#=> `sort': comparison of Fixnum with String failed (ArgumentError)
```

It allows us to hook into implementation and help with comparison, even though underlying sorting algorithm remains same (as it is abstracted from the user)

```
[1,3,4,5,"a","c","b", 2,10].sort { |i,j| 
    if i.class == String and j.class == String
        i <=> j
    elsif i.class == Fixnum and j.class == Fixnum
        i <=> j
    else
        0
    end
}
#=> [1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 10, "a", "b", "c"]
```

When writing code for your own problems, procedural abstraction can be used to ensure a procedure often breaks down its problem into sub-problems, and solves each sub-problems using separate procedure.  This allows, certain aspects to be extended later (as in above case, comparison could be extended - thanks to Ruby `blocks`, it was much easier).  [Template method pattern](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/06/12/coding-single-level-of-abstraction-principle/) is good technique to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you Wand.So are we doing abstraction unknowingly

Comment: I think we do abstraction knowingly and it is essential for good design.

Comment: Sorry but my concern is that.Suppose I made a function to calculate factorial.and user invoke it as fact(num). Then can we say It is abstraction.

Comment: Yes it is.  Because user of function does not have to worry about implementation.  The logic of computing factorial is nicely "abstracted"

Answer (score 3):

You are returning an array from the method. Data structures are implementation details. If you change the data structure used in the method, you will break the client code. So your example does not hide the implementation details. It does not encapsulate the design decisions so that the client's are insulated from the internal implementation details.

Answer (score 3):

> Definition of 'Abstraction' : the quality of dealing with ideas rather than events.

Referring to this answer [difference between abstraction and encapsulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742341/difference-between-abstraction-and-encapsulation#answer-743698) and my understanding I found that in your code the method `my_sort` fully justifies the `Encapsulation` as it encapsulates the `behavior` related to sorting of any `single dimension` array. However it lacks the `abstraction` as the method `my_sort` knows the type of data its gonna process on.

It would have justified `Abstraction` if it had not known / cared the type of data that comes in via params. In other words, it should have sorted any object that comes in no matter whether it is a list of `Fixnum` or `String` or other `sortable datatypes`.

**Encapsulation**:

We normally use access modifiers (`public`, `private`,..) to differentiate the data/behavior that are to be exposed to the `clients` and that are to be used `internally`. The public interface ( Exposed to clients ) are not subject to change as far as possible. However, the `private` are the behaviors that can change and should not in any case impact the expected behavior of the code that `clients` rely upon.
Also we separate the sensitive data/behavior to private/protected to prevent accidental modification / misuse. This makes client not to rely on the portion of the code that might change frequently.

- So one always need to segregate the `core logic` to `private` scope.

**Abstraction**:

Example:
In case of church there is an `abstraction` between the `confessor` and the `father / priest`. The confessor should not have any idea about the name or any detail of  the `priest` and vice-versa. Anyone can confess and yet hide his/her identity no matter how big mistakes/crimes he/she had committed.

Comment: Great !!
Nice explatnation but you missed my second question.Can you please cover this one.