# How can I create a wrapper around an Angular Component that only renames the component selector?

Tags: angular, reactjs, typescript

Coming from a React background, you can abstract out a library component in your app by renaming it like this:

`const MyAppTable = (props) => <LibraryTable ...props />;`

I want to do something similar in Angular, but am not sure how to get the 1:1 mapping of the component's behaviors. E.g., I want to do this:

`<my-app-table [input]="input" ></my-app-table>`

is the same as

`<library-table [input]="input" ></library-table> (plus all additional behavior found in component)`

Answer (score 0):

Isn't functional programming great?

You have to go the object oriented way with Angular. You can *extend* a component class and just update the component metadata that you want to change.

```js
@Component({selector: 'my-app-table'})
export class MyAppTableComponent extends LibraryTableComponent { 
     constructor() {
        super()
     }
}
```

You will have to match the constructor arguments of the base class. Otherwise Angular doesn't know what the dependency injections are.

This is a bit of an *anti-pattern* in object oriented programming. If the base class is updated to a new version this might break the functionality unless you update the derived classes.

So the preferred approach is called encapsulation. Which basically means to *wrap* around the other component, but there is nothing easy about that.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app-table',
    template: `<library-table [input]="input"></library-table>`
})
export class MyAppTableComponent {
    @Input() input: any;
}
```

The above requires more work but is *safer* from a code point of view.

[Difference between abstraction and encapsulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742341/difference-between-abstraction-and-encapsulation)

Comment: Thanks...yeah I've gone the encapsulation route for simple components, but when the component is complex, it becomes a real pain. I was hoping there was an easier, more straightforward way to do it, but I guess not :/