# How to "extend" and wrap a custom component or native element in Angular? (with React example)

Tags: angular

I currently try to figure out what would be the best way to "extend" a custom component or native element in Angular and wrap it with some custom markup? This is something I did quite often in React and which was quite forward. It could look like this:

```
type PasswordProps = {
  label: string;
} & Omit<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, 'type'>;

export const Password: FC<PasswordProps> = ({ label, ...inputProps }) => {
  const id = useId();
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
      <input name={id} type="password" {...inputProps} />
    </>
  );
};
```

I basically want specialized versions of existing components/elements and/or want to add some custom behavior. But I also want to "pass through" anything I don't touch.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078596/how-can-i-create-a-wrapper-around-an-angular-component-that-only-renames-the-com/57078909#57078909

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-your',
  template: `<label [for]="id">{{label}}</label><input [name]="id" type="password" />`
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() id: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```

I don't think there is the possibility to pass properties to the input field by default, you would have to define all required (or possible) properties as `@Input()` values of the component.

And call your component like `<app-your label="Your Label" id="passField"></app-your>`

Comment: So I really have to create one @Input for every possible attribute of an <input/> in this example? Crazy. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Pipo you might be able to create a `Directive` which handles these properties and that can be applied to any kind of input field, but I don't have an example for that at hand. But would maybe safe you from having the same `@Input`s when wrapping more input fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the component with a  native element, but you will start getting intro trouble if you need to override certain properties and you wish to change their type

```
export class YourComponent extends HtmlLabelElement implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```