# Java ApacheIO File download progress on console using copyInputStreamToFile

Tags: java, apache, file, url, download

I'm trying to find a way to use

```
copyInputStreamToFile(InputStream source, File destination)
```

to make a small progress bar in the console by file size. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean in the console? To print percentage of downloaded file?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer you can't, look at the source code of this method, I tried to track its execution path and it goes to this method at `IOUtils` class:

```
 public static long copyLarge(final InputStream input, final OutputStream output, final byte[] buffer)
                throws IOException {
            long count = 0;
            int n = 0;
            while (EOF != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, n);
                count += n;
            }
            return count;
        }
```

So, this functionality is [encapsulated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626/abstraction-vs-information-hiding-vs-encapsulation) by an API.

The long answer you can implement downloading method by yourself, by using relative parts of **IOUtils** and **FileUtils** libraries and add functionality to print percentage of downloaded file in a console:

This is a working kick-off example:

```
package apache.utils.custom;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
public class Downloader {

    private static final int EOF = -1;
    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 4;


    public static void copyInputStreamToFileNew(final InputStream source, final File destination, int fileSize) throws IOException {
        try {

            final FileOutputStream output = FileUtils.openOutputStream(destination);
            try {

                final byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
                long count = 0;
                int n = 0;
                while (EOF != (n = source.read(buffer))) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, n);
                    count += n;
                    System.out.println("Completed " + count * 100/fileSize + "%");
                }

                output.close(); // don't swallow close Exception if copy completes normally
            } finally {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
            }

        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(source);
        }
}
```

You should provide expected file size to this method which you can calculate by using this code:

```
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        int file_size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
```

Of course the better idea is to encapsulate the whole functionality in a single method.

Hope it will help you.